# Application uninstall automatically

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have my app on the Google play and some users are complaining that my app auto uninstalling every day. and users have to install again and again every day. i am using android:installLocation="preferExternal" in my androidmenifest.xml file.

any idea why its happening.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. No Android app can be uninstalled without user permission and root access. Google also removes malicious apps in the phones without asking the user.

Comment: FWIW, this is happening to me as a user with some of the apps that I install. The apps it happens to for me have `android:installLocation="auto"` and the system puts them on `sdcard` for whatever reason. It apparently has something to do with them going on to `sdcard`, as my other apps that aren't installed there don't get uninstalled.  I'm running on  a Motorola Atrix HD with Android 4.1.1.